# vertical stack numpy array in for loop

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, stack

I have a list(region_props_list), size = 37, which has the values of 2D numpy arrays like below.
(So, region_props_list[0] is a numpy array.)

I want to vertically stack all the data and make it as a new pandas DataFrame, which has a shape of ($$, 7)

How can I vertically stack the data with a for loop? can someone give me an advice?

[image: dd]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a for loop. You can use `np.vstack` instead:

```py
import numpy as np

lst = [np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]), np.array([[5, 6]]), np.array([[7, 8], [9, 10]])]
a = np.vstack(lst)
print(a)

# [[ 1  2]
#  [ 3  4]
#  [ 5  6]
#  [ 7  8]
#  [ 9 10]]
```

If your goal is to construct a dataframe, then you can use `itertools.chain` with `pd.DataFrame.from_records` (without even making the v-stacked array):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools

lst = [np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]), np.array([[5, 6]]), np.array([[7, 8], [9, 10]])]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lst))
print(df)

#    0   1
# 0  1   2
# 1  3   4
# 2  5   6
# 3  7   8
# 4  9  10
```

P.S. Please don't post a screenshot. Make a copy & paste-able minimal example which people can easily work on.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the real data I have to deal with is big, the list size is like hundreds. How can I use for loop for this then?

Comment: @MinwooKang Even if the data is large, I doubt that a `for` loop is better. On the contrary, I think you should avoid a `for` loop if possible, when a list is long. You can use `pd.DataFrame.from_records` directly to make a dataframe, with `itertools.chain`. In this way you don't even need to make the intermediate stacked array. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: If `DataFrame` is given a suitable array, it will use that without making a copy.  You might want to time test your alternatives.

Comment: @hpaulj That seems to be correct; modifying the original array changes the df as well.